# Footer at bottom while printing

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Here I want to fix the footer at bottom of all pages while printing the invoice. I have done with

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table{border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;}
            table thead tr th{vertical-align: middle;}

            #content{vertical-align: top;}

            p {
              margin-bottom: 0 !important;
              margin-top: 0!important;
            }
            table td {
                padding-left: 7px;
                padding-right: 7px;
            }
            h4 {
                margin-top: 0px!important;
                margin-bottom: 0px!important;
            }
            .align-right {
                text-align: right;
            }
            .align-center {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .total-bg {
                background-color: #e3e3e3;
                border: none;
                border-color: transparent;
            }
            p.signature {
                padding-top: 10%;
            }
            .logo img{
                width: 200px;
            }
            .pad-25{
                padding-left: 25px;
            }
            .logo {
                width: 200px;
                border-right-color: transparent;
            }
            @page {
    margin: 10mm;
  }
   body {
    font: 9pt sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;

    /* Avoid fixed header and footer to overlap page content */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 6pt;
    color: #777;
    /* For testing */
    background: red; 
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mar_bot">
                <table border="1px" style="padding: 5%;">
                    <table border="1px"> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.jpg"></td>
                            <td colspan="4"><h2 class="align-center">PROFORMA INVOICE</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px">
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">
                                <h4>EXPORTER</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Proforma Invoice No.:</b> EP1115 / 2018-19</p>
                                <p><b>Date:</b> 28-01-2019</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Buyers Confirmation Date:</b>27-01-2019</p>
                                <p><b>Other References:</b></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>IEC No.:</b></p>
                                <p><b>GSTIN No:</b></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <h4>CONSIGNEE</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Albaraka Company For Roasting and Packing Coffee,<br>Tripoli, Libya</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Country Of Origin:</b> India</p>
                                <p><b>Country Of Destination:</b> Libya</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Pre Carriage By</b><p>Road</p></td>
                            <td><b>Place of Receipt by Pre-Carrier</b><p>Any Indian Port</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><b>Terms & Payment</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Vessel/Flight</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td><b>Port of Loading</b><p>Any Indian Port</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><p>100% irrevocable LC at sight from a Prime Bankt</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Port of Discharge</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td><b>Final Destination</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><p><b>Price:</b> CIF, Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Marks & No</th>
                                        <th>Description of Goods</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Rate in USD</th>
                                        <th>Amount in USD</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">1</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">2</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">3</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="total-bg">
                                        <td colspan="3"><b>Amount Chargeable in USD</b><p>Four lakh Eighty Five Thousand Three Hundred Thirty Six only</p></td>
                                        <td class="align-right">Total</td>
                                        <td class="align-right"><b>485376.00</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">    
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 56%;"><h4>SPECIFICATION & PACKING DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Packing Details:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Load Ability</b><p class="pad-25">One 20 Feet load 19.6 MT.</p><p class="pad-25">Totally 10x20 Feet conatiner load 196 MT</p>
                                <b>Price Validity</b><p class="pad-25">The above price is validity upto 5th february 2019</p>
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h4>BANK DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Correspondent Bank:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>

                            </td>
                            <td><h4>BANK DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Beneficiary Bank:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>ARBITRATION</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Any and all controversy (ies) / disputes/difference / claim in tort arising out of or in connection with or in relation to this contract including its existence, validity or termination, shall be referred to and resolved by arbitration of sole/ three arbitrator nominated by the chamber Arbitration Tribunal (ChaAT) www.chaatindia.org, established by Tamilnadu chamber.</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>INTEREST</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Delayed Payment will be lieved with the rate of 15% per annum.</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>DECLARATION</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">We declare this shows the actual described and that all pariculars are true and correct.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </table>
        </div>
        
            <footer>
                <table class="footer">
                    <tr class="">
                        <td>
                            <p>For XYZ</p>
                            <p class="signature">Authorized Signatory</p>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <p>For Albaraka Company For Roasting and Packing Coffee</p>
                            <p class="signature">Authorized Signatory</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

When my table content extends linke this footer overlaps on the table. But what I really wants is to fix the footer at bottom withour overlapping. Is anyone help me to fix this problem.?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I always use this guide here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table{border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;}
            table thead tr th{vertical-align: middle;}

            #content{vertical-align: top;}

            p {
              margin-bottom: 0 !important;
              margin-top: 0!important;
            }
            table td {
                padding-left: 7px;
                padding-right: 7px;
            }
            h4 {
                margin-top: 0px!important;
                margin-bottom: 0px!important;
            }
            .align-right {
                text-align: right;
            }
            .align-center {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .total-bg {
                background-color: #e3e3e3;
                border: none;
                border-color: transparent;
            }
            p.signature {
                padding-top: 10%;
            }
            .logo img{
                width: 200px;
            }
            .pad-25{
                padding-left: 25px;
            }
            .logo {
                width: 200px;
                border-right-color: transparent;
            }
            @page {
    margin: 10mm;
  }
   body {
    font: 9pt sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;

    /* Avoid fixed header and footer to overlap page content */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
  text-align: center;
}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mar_bot">
                <table border="1px" style="padding: 5%;">
                    <table border="1px"> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.jpg"></td>
                            <td colspan="4"><h2 class="align-center">PROFORMA INVOICE</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px">
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">
                                <h4>EXPORTER</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Proforma Invoice No.:</b> EP1115 / 2018-19</p>
                                <p><b>Date:</b> 28-01-2019</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Buyers Confirmation Date:</b>27-01-2019</p>
                                <p><b>Other References:</b></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>IEC No.:</b></p>
                                <p><b>GSTIN No:</b></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <h4>CONSIGNEE</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Albaraka Company For Roasting and Packing Coffee,<br>Tripoli, Libya</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><b>Country Of Origin:</b> India</p>
                                <p><b>Country Of Destination:</b> Libya</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Pre Carriage By</b><p>Road</p></td>
                            <td><b>Place of Receipt by Pre-Carrier</b><p>Any Indian Port</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><b>Terms & Payment</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Vessel/Flight</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td><b>Port of Loading</b><p>Any Indian Port</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><p>100% irrevocable LC at sight from a Prime Bankt</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                            <td><b>Port of Discharge</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td><b>Final Destination</b><p>Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                            <td colspan="3"><p><b>Price:</b> CIF, Al Khoms/ El Khoms, Libya</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Marks & No</th>
                                        <th>Description of Goods</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Rate in USD</th>
                                        <th>Amount in USD</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">1</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">2</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="align-center">3</td>
                                        <td>Coffee Bean-Robusta Cherry AA</td>
                                        <td class="align-center">86.000 MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">2531.00 per MT</td>
                                        <td class="align-right">21760.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="total-bg">
                                        <td colspan="3"><b>Amount Chargeable in USD</b><p>Four lakh Eighty Five Thousand Three Hundred Thirty Six only</p></td>
                                        <td class="align-right">Total</td>
                                        <td class="align-right"><b>485376.00</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="1px" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">    
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 56%;"><h4>SPECIFICATION & PACKING DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Packing Details:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                <p class="pad-25">Robusta Cherry AA - packed in 60 Kg Jute Bag</p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Load Ability</b><p class="pad-25">One 20 Feet load 19.6 MT.</p><p class="pad-25">Totally 10x20 Feet conatiner load 196 MT</p>
                                <b>Price Validity</b><p class="pad-25">The above price is validity upto 5th february 2019</p>
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h4>BANK DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Correspondent Bank:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>

                            </td>
                            <td><h4>BANK DETAILS</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25"><b>Beneficiary Bank:</b></p>
                                <p class="pad-25"></p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>ARBITRATION</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Any and all controversy (ies) / disputes/difference / claim in tort arising out of or in connection with or in relation to this contract including its existence, validity or termination, shall be referred to and resolved by arbitration of sole/ three arbitrator nominated by the chamber Arbitration Tribunal (ChaAT) www.chaatindia.org, established by Tamilnadu chamber.</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>INTEREST</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">Delayed Payment will be lieved with the rate of 15% per annum.</p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><h4>DECLARATION</h4>
                                <p class="pad-25">We declare this shows the actual described and that all pariculars are true and correct.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </table>
        </div>
        
            <footer>
                <table id="footer">
                    <tr class="">
                        <td>
                            <p>For XYZ</p>
                            <p class="signature">Authorized Signatory</p>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <p>For Albaraka Company For Roasting and Packing Coffee</p>
                            <p class="signature">Authorized Signatory</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is always staying in the bottom now, just add your colors and whatever else CSS you may want or need, and you should be good.